# Merge primary and clipboard X selections

Tags: x11, clipboard

If there weren't two different selections (primary and clipboard), then it would work exactly as I want. How this would work is:

1. If anything wants to put text on primary or clipboard, the text gets put on both.
2. When anything reads from either primary or clipboard, the same text would be read every time, thanks to #1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Mentioning https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection for completeness, however the answers are outdated and don't work

Comment: See recent [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1504785/141314) about **CopyQ** tool, that can set primary and clipboard sync options very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Shell script with [Clipnotify](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify)

It is a program that simply exits whenever an X selection changes.
So put it in a while loop and when it exits, figure out if the clipboard or
the primary changed, and stuff the contents of the changed selection in the other
selection.

```bsh
get_selections_keep_newline() {
    c2=$(xsel -o --clipboard; printf x)
    c2=${c2%x}
    p2=$(xsel -o --primary  ; printf x)
    p2=${p2%x}
}

get_selections_keep_newline
while clipnotify; do
    c1=$c2
    p1=$p2
    get_selections_keep_newline
    if   [ "$c1" != "$c2" ]; then
        printf '%s' "$c2" | xsel -i --primary
    elif [ "$p1" != "$p2" ]; then
        printf '%s' "$p2" | xsel -i --clipboard
    fi
done
```

Save it as `mergexsel`, make it executable and let it run.

The function contains [a kludge to preserve trailing newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character)
(`abc\n` is different from `abc`); other than that the script is self-explanatory.

#### [Autocutsel](https://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/)

It must be run for both primary and clipboard (as [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/177541) shows).

```
autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD &
autocutsel -s PRIMARY   &
```

#### [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon), a GUI clipboard manager

Let it run in the background with `diodon &`.
Click the tray icon or issue another `diodon` command to pop up its GUI menu
with the history of clipboard contents and the "Preferences" item. Select "Preferences" and in the window that opens, check the items

- Use clipboard (Ctrl+C)
- Use primary selection
- Synchronize clipboards

**Further reading**: [Clipboard — Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Selections) for context and more clipboard managers.

Comment: of all the options, diodon worked most flawlessly and it was indeed simple and minmal to configure. In particular, autocutsel failed (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection#comment2465795_177541)) maybe because it is meant to synchronize primary / clipboard to older ring buffers, but not synchronize primary and clipboard with eachother. I'd suggest removing it from your answer but leaving the arch-wiki link in.

Comment: Also, a note for future users of this answer: diodon works flawlessly on ubuntu 20.04 (installed from apt) but on ubuntu 20.10 it's a bit weird -- issuing the "diodon" command makes it pop-up a context menu from where you can select "preferences", but the command itself exits immediately.

Comment: that superuser answer is incomplete, I found this limitation when I tested it: https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection#comment2465795_177541 . Can you please check if the same happens for you?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Yep, I did exhaustively check the Autocutsel solution (by looking at Vim registers) and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Weird. I hope you did not have diodon running when you performed that check. I checked it by looking at `xclip` outputs and found what I mentioned in that comment. I guess I'll just leave this  note here in case someone else encounters the same issue.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha I certified myself that Diodon was not running, but upon trying it again it seemed to me that a single time the contents were not synced, but it could be just my mind playing tricks on me, because I could not reproduce it again...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'm adding this in case someone else is looking. I get this result by using a gnome extension called "Pano" and one of its options in setrtings is to sync clipboards.