# How to alter the trigger for copying something to the PRIMARY selection in X11?

Tags: x11, clipboard, klipper

From my understanding, under X11 we have basically 2 ways to copy and paste stuff: the PRIMARY selection and the CLIPBOARD selection. Explicitly copying something with ctrl-c will utilize the clipboard selection and there are many applications that may manage your clipboard for you.

But what I'm interested in is altering the PRIMARY selection behavior, in particular I wish to make X11 stop automatically copying selected text to the primary selection.
**My end goal is to be able to select text with my mouse and then middle-click with my mouse-wheel if I wish to copy it** (or cut it if its easier to implement). I basically want to implement an extra step to copy stuff into PRIMARY.

I would also like to be able to paste this recently copied text by middle-clicking again the mouse. This is the default behavior for pasting the PRIMARY selection, so this should just work if we use the PRIMARY selection to copy stuff. (But if we somehow could remap everything to use CLIPBOARD we would gain the ability to paste images which I believe is impossible to do with PRIMARY)

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is this a xorg setting? Should I completely disable the PRIMARY selection and use some sort of keybinding application to implement this behavior with the CLIPBOARD selection? Is there a clipboard manager that can do this for me? I'm currently using Klipper, the clipboard manager that comes with KDE/plasma and this doesn't seem to be an option there.

Answer (score 2):

> My end goal is to be able to select text with my mouse and then middle-click
> with my mouse-wheel if I wish to copy it.

**Each X11 application decides (and oftentimes *hardcodes*) what binding it
uses to interact with Primary.**

The traditional way to own Primary (as known as copy to Primary) is to
simply make a selection and mouse-middle-click to paste from it.  This was
already the default for the [Athena Widget Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Athena_Widgets) (from the 80s, probably
the first X widgets library), as you can see in its [specification of the
text widget](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXaw/libXaw.html#Key_binding).  The binding can be altered for Athena and [Motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_%28software%29)
applications via a `translations` X-resource (examples in [Arch Wiki:
XTerm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#Primary_or_CLIPBOARD) and [scrolling a single line in Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138501)).  The bad news is that
such GUIs are legacy, and most modern X11 applications, based on Qt, GTK,
etc., not only do not use a `translations` resource, but also oftentimes
hardcode their keybidings.<sup>1</sup>

Moreover, although those Primary bindings are quite consolidated (the
same for programs as old as XTerm to modern ones as Firefox), they are
not written in stone.  For a mouse-aware [Ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) program
— e.g. Midnight Commander, Vim with mouse support enabled —, the copy
binding is Shift+MouseSelection.<sup>2</sup>

Although nothing prevents a clipboard manager from snooping the Primary
contents/ownership and controlling the Primary accordingly to arbitrary
keybindings, in a manner similar to one described in [Clipboard Managers section
here](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html), I don't think such a program exists yet.

Further reading:

- [Arch Wiki: Clipboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard)
- [Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html)

<sup>1: For what it's worth, I have never seen a GTK or Qt application that
would let me choose Primary keybindings.

2: [Vim can copy to or paste from Primary with the keyboard only](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection).</sup>

Comment: Actually Qt and GDK do use **X resources** (have "always" done so), but they don't use the *X Toolkit* library to access them ([XGetDefault](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/d/XGetDefault.html), for instance).  If they didn't use X resources, they would be far more limited than they are.  In the particular case you're mentioning though, it's mostly hard-coded stuff (very limited in comparison with other approaches).

Comment: @Quasímodo, then it seems that I would be better off by just configuring everything through CLIPBOARD. 
Is there a way to disable copy to PRIMARY? or at least make it so that middleclicking pastes from CLIPBBOARD rather than PRIMARY. I dont want both selections fighting for dominance and keybindings

Comment: @barzilay See if you want to [fuse PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628492) or maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213840. If neither is what you want, I'd recommend exploring the options of [some clipboard managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Managers) as many allow a special handling of Clip and Primary.

Comment: @Quasímodo, Sadly neither of those work for me. If i only fuse them, then selecting text will pollute the shared clipboard, if there is a way to disable copying to PRIMARY then this would work for me. I'm trying a few clipboard managers but none of them so far can completely block copy to PRIMARY :/ but thank you for your time

Comment: The X resources are the same.  I happened to recall this because I documented that stuff in [Xcursor](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES) recently.  X Toolkit just happens to have a nice interface to that stuff, but Qt and GDK can't do without it.

Comment: X Toolkit uses [this](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html#h3-Glyph-Cursor-APIs) part of Xcursor's API.  Qt and GDK use other parts (via libraries lacking documentation...).  But Xcursor uses X resources for either route.

Comment: The `translations` resource of course is specific to X Toolkit.  The answer which you linked to doesn't mention that detail, but at the end where it says "Most Gtk applications ignore X resources," that's incorrect.  Which resources they use depends on the libraries (hint: `Xft` is a library), but they all use ***some*** X resources.

Comment: @barzilay You're welcome. On the bright side, I guess to disable Primary is almost the same as not using it? Of course, feel free to open a new question, but as far as I know and where my research led, it is not possible to disable Primary.

Comment: @Quasímodo, Yeah, it doesn't seem to be possible to disable PRIMARY... On Wayland on the other-hand is another story, but I'm stuck with Xorg for the foreseeable future because of nvidia. And about not using PRIMARY, the thing is that I do want to use PRIMARY! I love being able to paste by middleclicking, but it just doesnt work for me if what I want to paste is always being overwritten by stuff that I mistakenly highlighted

Comment: @barzilay Well, then you can only use the clipboard and assign middle-click to paste from clipboard. That is totally doable, in case you're interested let me know.

Comment: @Quasímodo, yes I am! how can I do that? would it break other  features like middle-clicking a link to open it in a new tab? Also, is there a way to make something like copying into clipboard by middle-cliking highlighted text? or any other mousekeys combination if middle-clicking cant be used for both copying and pasting

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/276975. All you need to do is to assign one of those commands to middle-click in your window manager. But yeah, that will break middle-clicking links. Likewise, you could assign a right click to copy to clipboard, but again this will break other functionalities that require right clicks. It's all about avoiding conflicts. In case you have trouble but find the issue worth pursuing, I advise you to open a new question and to make your requirements as clear as possible upfront.